# What areas of geometry are used in computer graphics?

Tags: computational-geometry, graphics

I've taken intro to graphics and am interested in diving deeper into the subject.  My understanding is that the field depends a lot on geometry, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what geometry I should learn now that I've tackled the basics.

I found https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781852338343, but it basically doesn't go past high school geometry and linear algebra.  On the opposite end of the spectrum, I've found papers on arxiv about homological groups in geometric topology, but I assume that it would not be necessary to understand the cutting edge of extremely theoretical areas of geometry.  What areas of geometry would it make sense for me to study in order to survey the kind of math one would find while doing research in computer graphics?  Are there any resources you can recommend?

Comment: I suggest studying instead computer graphics. The textbooks will mention the prerequisites (trigonometry, linear algebra, and in some cases, PDEs), and will teach you the rest.

Comment: "Computer graphics" is also a quite large area. It covers everything from 3D printing to physical simulation, and different subfields of graphics require different subfields of geometry.